# Bluetooth keyboard disconnect after few seconds

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth, keyboard, raspi-config

I've recently bought the new raspby pi 3, and i decided to use it with a bluetooth keyboard and wireless mouse.
For the wireless mouse I haven't spot any problem (it has its USB-dongle)...but the bluetooth keyboard...man, it drive me crazy! :(
I succesfully pair it and connect. After that I could use it, but if I wait 5-10 seconds, without pressing any button, it automatically disconnect...and if I press a button after 3 seconds it reconnects automatically.
It seems as it goes in timeout in about few seconds of inactivity.
The annoying thing is this continuos connect/reconnect :(
I try using this keyboard with my android phone and I haven't find any problem. It stays connect for minutes (exactly 15 minutes as describe from the vendor).
How I could resolve this annoying problem? :(
Thanks guys for the attention.

**AFTER CHECK THE LOG:**
I execute btmon and this is what i have found:

> Bluetooth monitor ver 5.23
>   = New Index: B8:27:EB:B0:84:EA (BR/EDR,UART,hci0)
>   Unknown packet (code 8 len 0)
>   * Unknown packet (code 10 len 8)
>       ea 84 b0 eb 27 b8 0f 00
>
> ACL Data RX: Handle 11 flags 0x02 dlen 14
>   Channel: 65 len 10 [PSM 0 mode 0] {chan 0}
>           a1 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>
> HCI Event: Disconnect Complete (0x05) plen 4
>   Status: Success (0x00)
>           Handle: 11
>           Reason: Connection Timeout (0x08)
>   @ Device Disconnected: 20:73:00:97:34:11 (0) reason 1
>
> HCI Command: Write Scan Enable (0x03|0x001a) plen 1
>   Scan enable: Page Scan (0x02)
>   HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4
>   Write Scan Enable (0x03|0x001a) ncmd 1
>           Status: Success (0x00)
>
> HCI Event: Connect Complete (0x03) plen 11
>   Status: Page Timeout (0x04)
>           Handle: 12
>           Address: 20:73:00:97:34:11 (OUI 20-73-00)
>           Link type: ACL (0x01)
>           Encryption: Disabled (0x00)
>   @ Connect Failed: 20:73:00:97:34:11 (0) status 0x04

I also tried to set IdleTimeout = 0 in bluetooth config, without success :(

Answer (score 3):

You should run diagnostic tools like `btmon` (and perhaps `dmesg`) in a terminal, reproduce the disconnect problem and analyse the logs to narrow the problem down.

Without the logs, one thing you can try is to disable power management for the bluetooth device. Try running something like

```
echo on > /sys/class/bluetooth/hci*/power/control
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I check the log of **btmon** - read my edit